# How to easily check the implementation of embeded functions in Julia language?

Tags: julia, numerical-methods, scientific-computing, ijulia-notebook

In Matlab, it is possible to check how (most?) of the embeded functions are implemented by typing `edit function_name`. The mentioned command open `function_name` code in editor.

I wonder if there's similar way in Julia language (for example how Cholesky's method has been implemented)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's the `@edit` macro call. You have to pass it a function call (not the function name) as it will open the right method.
Example:

```
@edit "a" * "string"
```

opens the file `/base/strings/basic.jl` in line:

```
(*)(s1::AbstractString, ss::AbstractString...) = string(s1, ss...)
```

while

```
@edit 1 * 2
```

opens the file `/base/int.jl` in line:

```
(*)(x::T, y::T) where {T<:BitInteger} = mul_int(x, y)
```

To change the editor used, you can customize the environment variable "EDITOR". Example:

```
ENV["EDITOR"] = "nano"
```

There is also the macro @less to print the function